# OpenGL camera pitch, yaw and roll rotation

Tags: c++, opengl, camera, rotation, trigonometry

I am trying to create a class to control the camera in OpenGL.
I have three methods to change the pitch yaw and roll of the camera. 
The methods take a float parameter to use as the amount of rotation to add.

The code in these methods is where I need help. The rotations are stored in a Vector3.
So far for the change pitch method I have:

```
void changePitch(float degrees)
{
    float rads = MathHelp::degreesToRadians(degrees);
    m_rotation.x += cos(m_rotation.y) * rads;
}
```

This is as far as I could get by myself. It kind of works, the camera looks up and down while facing up or down the z axis and not while looking down the x axis. I tried adding z rotation:

```
m_rotation.z += sin(m_rotation.y) * rads;
```

But that didn't go very well.

Comment: The conversion from degree to radians must be applied before it goes into the trigonometric functions. Not multiplicated with the result of sin, cos or tan.

Comment: The angles are stored in the vector as radians.

Comment: So? `rads` is a constant that's to be multiplied in the angle that goes into sin, not to the result of it, i.e. ``cos(m_rotation.y * rads)` – however you can not simply "add" rotations. That's simply not how it works. Concatenation of rotations is multiplicative.

Comment: rads is the conversion of the parameter (float degrees) into a radian. This is the amount to turn by.

Comment: This method would be used to change the pitch by the given amount in degrees if that makes it easier to understand.

Comment: Slight aside - if you're using Euler Angles (pitch, yaw and roll), look out for [Gimbal Lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock).

Answer (score 3):

Assume you have the `upVector`, `lookAtVector` and `rightVector` 3D vectors that point towards up, looking at direction and right of your camera. Then, to properly increment pitch you should do the computation as follows:

```
void changePitch(angle) {
    angle = DegreeToRadian(angle);

    // Rotate lookAtVector around the right vector
    // This is where we actually change pitch
    lookAtVector = Normalize3dVector(viewDir * cos(angle) + UpVector * sin(angle));

    // Now update the upVector
    upVector = CrossProduct(rightVector, lookAtVector);
}
```

In the above excerpt, names of the arbitrarily used functions are self-explanatory.

Comment: Ah ok, this kind of makes sense to me. I will give it a try later!

Comment: How do I add these to the final camera matrix to apply the rotation?

Comment: But what is "viewDir"?